# Python3 Alarm Function

Tags: python-3.4

I'm trying to create an alarm function with Python3. The below code does work but it doesn't seem like this is the most optimal way of achieving something like this. Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import os
import time

def alarm():
    os.system('amixer -D pulse sset Master 30%')     # >> Set initial volume
    for beep in range(0, 20):
        time.sleep(.002)
        os.system('play --no-show-progress --null --channels 1 synth %s sine %f' % (.08, 2500))

alarm()
```

Comment: You may want to ask at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.